# Executing a set of commands inside a new bash instance from as script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, heredoc

I'm trying execute a set of commands in a new `bash` session:

```
exec bash <<- EOF
   ln -snf $JDK_REPO'/jdk'$1 $CURRENT;
   JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $CURRENT);
   echo $JAVA_HOME;
   export PATH= $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;
   exec usejdk 
   EOF
```

I get this **error** :

```
 warning: here-document at line 46 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

I tried to debug it with [whatswrongwithmyscript](http://www.whatswrongwithmyscript.com/), I get :

```
Use <<- instead of << if you want to indent the end token.
```

Any suggestion to execute a set of commands in a **new** `bash` instance  ?

Comment: Like
 a Makefile, you *must* indent with **tab** chars. see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Interesting, thanks @glennjackman , I will try it with the herdoc approach again to make sure that I'm not doing white-spaces killer mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doing it this way works for me:

```
cmd="
   ln -snf $JDK_REPO'/jdk'$1 $CURRENT;
   JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $CURRENT);
   echo $JAVA_HOME;
   export PATH= $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;
   exec usejdk"
bash <<< "$cmd"
```

The `bash <<< "$cmd"` is equivalent to `echo "$cmd" | bash` or `bash -c "$cmd"`

Comment: Thanks @Lynch , I see `<<<` for the first time, white-spaces are killing me when writing bash scripts, first steps :)

Comment: Taking the habit to always quotes your variables is a good thing. otherwise strange things happen.

Comment: strange things always happen with `bash`.